# Trouble getting text using TextField of UIAlertController in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to get label for saving an image using the TextField of UIAlertController in Xcode 10.3. The code is the following:

```
    {
      ...
   saveLabel = saveImage(imagePath: imagePath, image: image)
   print(saveLabel)
      ...
    }


 func saveImage(imagePath: String, image: UIImage) -> String {

    var label = "placeholder"
    let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)
    if fileManager.createFile(atPath: imagePath as String, contents: data, attributes: nil) {
        let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Saved", message: "Label photo", preferredStyle: .alert)
        myAlert.addTextField { (textField) in textField.placeholder = "Enter Label" }
        let labelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Enter", style: .default, handler: { (_) in
            label = myAlert.textFields?[0].text ?? "Saved" })
        myAlert.addAction(labelAction)
        self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return label
    } else {
        print("failed to save")
    }

    return "not right label"
}
```

Everything seems to work, e.g. the image was saved, except that the label = "placeholder" was returned and printed. The text I entered into the dialog box was never returned. Using debug to step through the code I found that the dialog box actually appeared after the function has returned and the print commanded has been executed. Does anybody have any idea what I did wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

got around the problem by forcing the code that used the user input into the handler, e.g. print(saveLabel), as follows:

```
    {
      ...
    savedSuccess = saveImage(imagePath: imagePath, image: image)

      ...
    }

  func saveImage(imagePath: String, image: UIImage) -> Bool {
    var label = ""
    let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)
    if fileManager.createFile(atPath: imagePath as String, contents: data, attributes: nil) {
        let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Saved", message: "Label photo", preferredStyle: .alert)
        myAlert.addTextField { (textField) in textField.placeholder = "Enter Label" }
        let labelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Enter", style: .default, handler: { (_) in
            label = myAlert.textFields?[0].text ?? "" 
         if label !="" {
              ....
            print(label)
              ....
            })

    myAlert.addAction(labelAction)
    self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    return True
} else {
    print("failed to save")
    return False
}
```

}